# how can I prevent the same url return different response?

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

Now I am trying to use **scrapy** to crawl a website.

I find that given the same url, the response of the request can be different.
It seems that it is two versions of the website. I have also used the same user-agent.

Are there some ways to let the response be consistent ? 
Or I can only analyze the version of each response and then extract the item use different XPath ?

The response.headers from the scrapy shell is like this:

```
{'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate',
 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
 'Date': 'Fri, 04 Dec 2015 18:56:59 GMT',
 'Server': 'nginx/1.6.2',
 'Set-Cookie': 'auth_token=hello; domain=www.medhelp.org; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT',
 'X-Rack-Cache': 'miss',
 'X-Request-Id': '70f23a01ac124fd58acc9e9e7bafb609',
 'X-Runtime': '0.150452',
 'X-Ua-Compatible': 'IE=8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

that totally depends on the site, not scrapy. Something that could be useful on this case, could be to check the `response.headers`, specifically the `Last-Modified` header which should be returned with date information of the last time it was modified.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I am a little confused. The 'response.headers' returns: '{...,
 'X-Ua-Compatible': 'IE=8'}
'  But when I view the response, I can see in the 'head' section that '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">' And this meta information is the same in all versions of responses. I don't know whether this could be the problem.

Comment: first headers are not the same as meta information, and some sites could not return that `Last-Modified` information.

Comment: yes, there is no `Last-Modified` information of this site.